# Can I have static subscript in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

The title pretty much explains the question, I would like to do something like this: `MyStruct[123]` without the need to call a function (`MyStruct.doSomething(123)`) or create an instance (`MyStruct()[123]`). Having it on classes or structs would be ok.

Comment: The title is unclear. Do you want an array whose size is a compile-time constant, or do you mean something else?

Comment: Something else, the parameter sent to the subscript could be anything: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Subscripts.html

Comment: I don't think you can have a subscript on a class, only on an instance of a class.

Comment: @gfpacheco maybe a global var with private init?

Comment: @onmyway133 that would look like a static subscript, while not really being one. Upvoting since that could work for someone else =]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Short answer is no. Static is limited to methods and properties within a struct or class.  Subscripts are operators and cannot be set to static.  This is doable:

```
struct TimesTable {
    let multiplier: Int
    subscript(index: Int) -> Int {
        return multiplier * index
    }
}
let threeTimesTable = TimesTable(multiplier: 3)
print("six times three is \(threeTimesTable[6])")
// prints "six times three is 18"
```

but you do have to make an object of threeTimesTable (in this case). Additionally this is worth looking at:

http://www.codingexplorer.com/custom-subscripts-swift/

Comment: That's what I found out too, accepted since you wrote a nice answer =]

Answer (score 11):

Since Swift 5.1 static and class subscripts are possible ([Proposal SE-0254](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0254-static-subscripts.md)). They are called *[type subscripts](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Subscripts.html#ID609)*.

So this can be done now:

```
struct MyStruct {
    static var values = ["a", "b", "c"]
    static subscript(index: Int) -> String {
        values[index]
    }
}

print(MyStruct[2]) // prints c
```